# Segmentation fault in linked list with mutex

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to create thread which insert data in linked list with mutex, but just getting segmentation fault. I have to set many thread with various data and just in the process of experiment with one data(like '10') and one thread.

```
typedef struct NODE{
    int data;
    struct NODE* next;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
}node;

node* head;

void* list1(void* args){
    node *prev, *new_node;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&new_node->lock);
    new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
    new_node -> data = 10;
    new_node -> next = NULL;
    if(head -> next == NULL){
        head = new_node;
    }else{
        prev = head;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&prev->lock);
        while(prev -> next != NULL){
            prev = prev -> next;
        }
        prev -> next = new_node;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prev->lock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&new_node->lock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&prev -> lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&new_node -> lock);
}
```

```
int main(void){
    void *thread_result;
    int status, cnt;
    pthread_t thread_id[1];
    head -> next = NULL;
    printf("%d\n", 1);

    status = pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL, list1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id[0], &thread_result);
    node* curr = head -> next;
    while(curr -> next != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", curr -> data);
        curr = curr -> next;
        free(curr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

free() is required by dynamic allocation, so entered in main() function, but terminal says i'm getting segmentation fault.

What is my mistake? And how to identify problem efficiently? i'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Debugger........

Comment: Where and when does the Segmentation fault appear? If not a debugger, run `printf()` until you localized the piece of code that crashes. Most of the time, you will then be able to find it yourself.

Comment: ```printf ("1")``` in the middle was for that. However, it was difficult to find what the problem was because even that was not printed.

Answer (score 0):

If `head` is `NULL` then `head -> next` will give you a segmentation fault.
Replace `head -> next = NULL (in main)` and `head -> next == NULL (in list1)` with `head = NULL` and `head == NULL` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and i can sort out a little. But still i got a segmentation fault.  ```print(1)``` for interim confirmation is carried out and i think thread had some problems. what can i do?